# Base 64 decoding issue (special characters) iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, base64

I have some problem for decoding string from base 64 encoded string. I am using base64.h and base 64.m files downloaded from the following link.
http://cdn.imthi.com/e6cef8/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip

This is my code :

```
[Base64 initialize];
NSData * data = [Base64 decode:encodedString];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                                             length:[data length]
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and base 64 encoded string looks like below :

> AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADQodLwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANCi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tQnJhbmNoLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0NCg0KLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS1IZWFkcXVhcnRlcnMtLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLQ0KDQotLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tDQozLzUvMjAxMiAgIDU6MTU6NTQgQU0gICAgIFJlZzogICBVU0VSDQpSZWNlaXB0IzogMTU5OSAgICAgICAgICAgIFN0b3JlOiAxDQpDYXNoaWVyOiAgVVN

When we tried to decode the string i am getting some special characters like inverted question mark but when we try to decode the same base 64 string using the below tool (http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) we are not getting any special characters.

Comment: is this issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If your using a html page to output the string, the html document itself needs to know it charset. Try

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

in your html document.